# How to install the latest version of a package using composer in the command line?

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-5

i'm trying to install the latest version of cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable that is compatible with laravel 5, i believe this is the 3.0.0-alpha / dev-master version.
however when i run `composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` it try's to pull in version 2.x witch is only compatible with Laravel 4.

```
Using version ~2.0 for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.0 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.1 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.2 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.3 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.4 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable 2.0.5 requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.2
9, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.0.14.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.14].
    - Installation request for cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable ~2.0 -> satisfiable by cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

i have also tried the following commands along with some others i came across while searching with no success.

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable --dev

composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable --prefer-dist
```

iv been searching around to try and figure this out, but everything iv tried hasn't done the trick for me. Can someone point me in the right direction please? i'm still rather new at this.

Kind regards, Makka

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

https://packagist.org/packages/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the version?

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable:3.0.0-alpha
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! i did not realize you could append a version number  like that.
Thanks again!
Makka